# Copy but not move

Tags: c++11

In C++0x, is it legal / expected that some classes can be copied but not moved? I'm looking at implementing a heterogenous class that resizes, and I'm not sure I could handle it if some classes needed copying and some needed moving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's legal for a class to be copyable but not movable:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    /* Copyable... */
    MyClass(const MyClass&);
    MyClass& operator= (const MyClass&);

    /* ... but not movable. */
    MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator= (MyClass&&) = delete;
};
```

However, I can't think of a good reason as to why anyone would want to do this.  Knowing C++ coders (like me!) though, I think that you should anticipate that this might come up.

Out of curiosity, what code are you relying on that would break if a class was copyable but not movable?

Comment: It's a heterogeneous stack that resizes. I guess if I want C++03 compatibility with the minimum effort, I should allow for both.

Comment: Hmm... what specifically is in the code that breaks with copyable, immobile (I guess that's a reasonable term for it?) objects?  I'm curious since I've never come across this before.

Comment: It's a good thing you said that. For some reason, I had in mind that objects that were moved from didn't need destructing. Whoops.

Comment: As a side node, in such a case, it's better not to explicitly declare the move constructors, because that will actually make a call like `MyClass m = f();` (`f()` returning a `MyClass`) ill-formed, as it will select a move constructor that was `= delete`'ed. It would be better to just declare the copy constructor - in such a case, no move constructor is created automatically, therefor you would be fine.

Comment: Adding to what litb said earlier, std::swap can no longer swap MyClass objects. Compiler error on g++ 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that making the move constructor protected/private is a way of limiting the ability to move objects of that class. If you can expect that in a template? I don't think so. You'd need `std::enable_if` for that kind of check.